# Классы функций в C++

Tags: классы, c++

В C++ с помощью классов мы задаем иерархию объектов. Инициализируя члены производного класса, мы создаем объект.
Вопрос: как можно создать иерархию функций? Инициализируя члены, которые мы создавали бы конкретный экземпляр функции.
То есть, и в перегруженных, и в шаблонных функциях работает один и тот же код. Мне же нужно размазать сам код по иерархии, как мы размазываем данные по классам, создав таким образом множество сущностей разного уровня абстракции.

Comment: а можно как то уточнить задачу? а то слишком абстрактно она звучит.

Comment: А чем отличается иерархия функций от иерархии классов? Определите в вашей иерархии классов виртуальный `operator ()`, вот и всё. (Да, формально это не функция, а функтор, но какая разница?)

Comment: Обычно создавая экземпляр класса мы создаем как бы список данных.  Есть ли что ни будь что позволило создать список процедур?

Comment: А что мешает сделать список (или другой контейнер) абстрактных структур, каждая из которых содержит дескриптор функции (естественно, включающий собственно указатель на функцию).

Comment: можно конечно, но вообще хотелось бы использовать элементы языка, что бы легче организовать иерархию.
Например так:
sort a(b);
вызывает конструктор класса sort,который получая аргументом обьект b, проинициализировал бы члены  класса sort и  тем самым  создал бы обьект-функцию a.

Comment: @oasistravels, больше конкретики. 

Вы хотите, что бы конструктор `sort()` как-то проанализировал класс `b` (или его конкретное воплощение -- экземпляр с именем `b`) и выбрал подходящую функцию сортировки (скорее достаточно компаратор)?

Ну, наверное тогда конструктор должен получить некое описание `b` на каком-то метаязыке. 

Вы какие-то интересующие Вас конкретные примеры кода привести можете?

Comment: да спасибо, функторы, уже изучаю

Comment: > Обычно создавая экземпляр класса мы создаем как бы список данных.

для меня классы - это всегда и "список данных" и список "функций".

Comment: @oasistravels, с точки зрения машинного представления, класс - это та же структура и объект класса представлен в памяти именно структурой данных, а методы - это те же функции, которые не тиражируются, но неявно получают указатель на объект, т.е. на структуру данных, как указатель this. Знание этого полезно, но важно представление об объекте как о целостном: данные объекта определяют его состояние, а методы - поведение, реакцию на внешние воздействия (вызов этого метода).